dpkg:error;depend.prob-ms;errors process:linux-headers6.8.0-51-gen;linux-headers-gen;linux-gen;linux-image6.8.0-51-gen
Specs:
   OS: Xubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
   Host: Inspiron 7559 1.3.1
   Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic
   Uptime: 2 mins
   Packages: 2718 (dpkg), 14 (flatpak), 21 (snap)
   Shell: bash 5.2.21
   Resolution: 1920x1080
   DE: Xfce
   WM: Xfwm4
   CPU: Intel i7-6700HQ (8) @ 3.500GHz
   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
   GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530
When trying to update and upgrade - on terminal
with this: sudo apt update --fix-missing
then with this command:
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
gives at the end these errors ..........
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-51-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/vhba-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vhba/20211218/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 failed for vhba(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-51-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/vhba-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vhba/20211218/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 failed for vhba(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.8.0-51.52); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-51-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/vhba-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vhba/20211218/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 failed for vhba(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic
Current status: 0 (-101) upgradable.
#
When trying to fix - similar problem again
#
XXXXXX@xxxxxxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for user_one: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-46 linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-46-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-46-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-51-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/vhba-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vhba/20211218/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 failed for vhba(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exi
t status 11
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failur
e.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous fail
ure.
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.8.0-51.52); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (6.8.0-51.52) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-51-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/vhba-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vhba/20211218/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-51-generic/x86_64 failed for vhba(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-51-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-generic
linux-image-6.8.0-51-generic
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#
After sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
system become unbootable, going to timeshit to restore
#
my uname -r
6.8.0-49-generic

